# Display the page based on product when click

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a page where it displays several images, for example, click the milo image and it goes to a page where it shows all image of milo, but when i click other page, for example, tea, it also shows image of milo. I need to display the page base on the image clicked

```
        <?php  
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product ORDER BY id ASC"; //order by ID ascending order  
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
    {  
    ?>
<div id="products" class="productsContainer">
    <div class="responsive">   <!-- OUTER BOX OF PRODUCT -->
        <div class="gallery"> <!-- INNER BOX FOR PRODUCT -->
                <a href="box.php"><img src="images/<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a><br /> <!-- IMAGE OF PRODUCTS -->
                <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></h4>  <!-- NAME OF PRODUCT -->
                <h4 class="text-danger">$ <?php echo $row["price"]; ?></h4>  <!-- PRODUCT PRICE -->
                <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="form-control" value="1" />  <!-- QUANTITY PRODUCT -->
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>" />  <!-- NOT SHOWN -->
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>" />  <!-- NOT SHOWN -->
                <input type="button" name="add_to_cart" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-warning form-control add_to_cart" value="Add to Cart" />  <!-- ADD TO CART BUTTON -->

        </div>  
    </div> 
</div>
    <?php  
        }  
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how much Ajax / Javascript you know, but in this case you could use something along those lines for your script to display the image you want to see based on their id, as the user clicks on image `WHERE id = ?` return the value via an ajax return:

```
<script>
    function getProduct(val) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "box.php",
        data:'id='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#product-echo").html(data);
        }
        });
    }
</script>

<?php  
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product ORDER BY id ASC"; //order by ID ascending order  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{  
    ?>
    <div id="products" class="productsContainer">
        <div class="responsive">   <!-- OUTER BOX OF PRODUCT -->
            <div class="gallery"> <!-- INNER BOX FOR PRODUCT -->
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getProduct('<?php echo $row['id']; ?>')"><img src="images/<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a><br /> <!-- IMAGE OF PRODUCTS -->
                    <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></h4>  <!-- NAME OF PRODUCT -->
                    <h4 class="text-danger">$ <?php echo $row["price"]; ?></h4>  <!-- PRODUCT PRICE -->
                    <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="form-control" value="1" />  <!-- QUANTITY PRODUCT -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>" />  <!-- NOT SHOWN -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>" />  <!-- NOT SHOWN -->
                    <input type="button" name="add_to_cart" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-warning form-control add_to_cart" value="Add to Cart" />  <!-- ADD TO CART BUTTON -->

            </div>  
        </div> 
    </div>
<?php  
}  
?>


<div id="product-echo"></div>
```

Logical explanation of code:

User loads the page and all the products come up > he sees a product he likes > clicks on it (`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getProduct('<?php echo $row['id']; ?>')">`) > engages Ajax call `getProduct()` which requires one param - the `val` (in this case == id) > results come back to the `#product-echo` div.

That leads us to `box.php` where we simply run a query to check `if` ID has been submitted, then what ID is equals to, and finally give us a result.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tb1_product WHERE id = " . $id;

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
    {
        // layout content as your heart so desires...
    }
}
?>
```

Now, this is very simple, I recommend a bit more time spent on handling the calls on the `box.php` side, but it should you give a pretty good idea of how to get the job done.

If you do not feel comfortable using Ajax calls, you could always send the user to `box.php` and have the product's element come up.

Comment: very helpful answer! im not really good at ajax, may i know what is the val for?

Comment: Thank you very much, I hope it helps you understand it a bit better,, `val` defines which ID is being selected.

Answer (score 0):

pass the product Id in into the box.php (i believe box.php contains code for image details or product details)

eg:  `<a href="box.php?id=".$row['id']><img src="images/<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a><br />`

in php use get to get the id variable

box.php

```
<?php 
  $id = $_GET['id'];

?>
```